# How to remove null from date in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

No matching signature for operator != for argument types: DATETIME, INT64. Supported signature: ANY != ANY at [5:7]

I'm getting the above error when i enter the code "where starttime <>0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that NULL is not the same as Numeric 0.

What you should do is compare the starttime column with NULL value.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM my_table
WHERE starttime IS NOT NULL
```

Hope this helps you in your issue.